# Infinite Scroll on both Directions ( Horizontally & Vertically ) in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, infinite-scroll

I want to implement 2 way infinite scrolling. Horizontal pagination as well as Vertical Pagination in Jetpack compose only.

```
LazyRow(){
       LazyColumn()
         {
           // Horizontal item will be shown here
           // Horizontal Pagination
         }
       //Vertical Pagination
    }
```

Edit 1: I am implementing something like Netflix UI. Where there is a category and items related to that. You can scroll them horizontally. Other than that you can also scroll page vertically to see more category content. I am able to implement vertical pagination using below code.

```
@Composable
fun Pagination(
    listState: LazyListState, buffer: Int = 5, action: () -> Unit
) {
    var lastTotalItems = -1
    val loadMore = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val layoutInfo = listState.layoutInfo
            val totalItemsNumber = layoutInfo.totalItemsCount
            val lastVisibleItemIndex = (layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index ?: 0) + 1
            val loadMore = lastVisibleItemIndex > (totalItemsNumber - buffer) && (lastTotalItems != totalItemsNumber)
            
            loadMore
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(loadMore) {
        snapshotFlow { loadMore.value }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .collect {
               
                if (it) {
                    lastTotalItems = listState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount
                    action()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

But problem is how can i keep listState for every category for horizontal scroll. If i will update the category data then it will recompose all the items again. I dont think that will be a good idea.

Comment: users do not like this kind of questions without describing what is your problem.
you should describe what exactly you need

Comment: @MohammadBaqer Added more details.